# Where to find child themes?

Tags: themes, search, child-theme

Is there a method of finding child themes?

I tried searching the [Wordpress Theme Directory](https://wordpress.org/themes/search/twenty%20fifteen/), but most themes do not seem to have children. Some featured in the "Twenty Fifteen" search actually are not "official" child themes. For example, [Openness](https://wordpress.org/themes/openness/) mentions the parent theme in their description, but it does not have the "child theme" tag like [Tiny Hestia](https://wordpress.org/themes/tiny-hestia/) below.

[image: "Hestia child theme" clearly tagged by Wordpress]

ThemeIsle.com has a "From clients - See what else can be done with this theme" list showing theme modifications, very similar to what I would expect from a child theme list.

[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason you only want child themes? If it's because you've seen people say that to safely customise a theme you should use a child theme, be aware that this only applies to brand new child themes that you create. Changes to a publicly available child theme have the same potential to be overwritten by an update, but there's no workaround because there's no such thing as grandchild themes.

Comment: It takes me quite a long time to find a free Wordpress theme I like. As I start to use a theme, I often discover UX problems. My impression is that a lot of users would have the same experience and someone would have already modified the theme appropriately. @JacobPeattie

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Your problem will be that relatively few of those people are going to go to the effort of publicly releasing the result. More often they’ll just modify for their needs and hold onto it.

Comment: Thanks. When my original searches came up empty, I wondered about that. However, there is precedent for finding examples of theme modifications. for example, ThemeIsle.com has a "theme in use" list. I'll update the question with a screenshot.